# Import files with custom extension into typescript

Tags: json, typescript

I'm trying to import into typescript a file whose content is a json structure, but the file doesn't have the ".json" extension; it's called "file.configuration". Is there a way to import this in typescript?

file.configuration looks like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

Comment: That's not JSON! It would have quotes around `foo`

Comment: Let me correct that

Comment: This will depend on your runtime and loaders. NodeJS? Webpack? SystemJS? They will need to be configured to process such files as JSON. To make TypeScript allow the import, add `declare module "*.configuration";` somewhere, but TypeScript won't provide intellisense like it can for `.json` files with `--resolveJsonModule`

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be the simplest to just fall back on `require()` for these.

I think a more usual way to handle this, is to use `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync()` and JSON.parse.